# Send ajax GET request if condition is met

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is my JS code. However, it only executed the last ajax request. Is there anyway to put them in If statement so that

if (main-content.html is loaded), it will execute `xmlhttp.open("GET","main-content-city.php?q="+str,true)
xmlhttp.send();`

elseif (child-content is loaded), execute: `xmlhttp.open("GET","child-content-city.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();`

```
<script>
function sortResult(str)
{
   if (str=="")
   {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
    return;
   } 
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","main-content-city.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.open("GET","child-content-city.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

My index.php file is like this and using GET method to navigate between main-content.html and child-content.html.

```
 <?php
include('header.html');
include('main-content.html');
include('footer.html');
?>
```

My main-content and child-content is like this:

```
<div id="result">
Content displayed here
</div>
```

Comment: The logic of your code is flawed. Also, you may want to look into a library that can handle this for you... something like Angular.

Comment: use php to set a javascript variable for the url, then use that variable in `xmlhttp.open()`

Answer (score 0):

Take all the following code which will be identical for both ajax calls and make a separate function i..e

```
function ajaxCall (){
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
 }
```

}

Then when you call ajaxCall you simply add relevant SEND:

```
 function whatEver(){
 if (main-content.html is loaded)
 { ajaxCall();  
 xmlhttp.open("GET","main-content-city.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 else if (child-content is loaded)
 {
 ajaxCall(); 
 xmlhttp.open("GET","child-content-city.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 }
```

Comment: I assume "if (main-content.html is loaded)" and "else if (child-content is loaded)" are something that you have a code for and these are just sort of nicknames otherwise the code wont work as it is. How do you know if the main-content or child-content is loaded? When you know then you can tie them to the above code.